# need to find out items from the same table on basis of event type

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `JOB_LOGS` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_id` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_EL_EVENT` (`event`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_EL_JOB_ID` (`job_id`));
```

here in this table the posibble values for the event are ('ADDED','INPROGRESS' , 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED')

example data set
1st job:

```
 1. id=1,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job1,event=ADDED
 2. id=2,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:01:00",job_id=Job1,event=INPROGRESS
 3. id=3,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:01:50",job_id=Job1,event=SUCCESS
```

2nd job:

```
 1. id=4,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job2,event=ADDED
 2. id=5,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:01:01",job_id=Job2,event=INPROGRESS
 3. id=6,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:01:53",job_id=Job2,event=FAILED<br/>
```

3rd job:

```
 1. id=7,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=ADDED<br/>
```

4th job:

```
 1. id=8,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=ADDED<br/>
 1. id=9,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=INPROGRESS<br/>
```

here from this data set I want to get jobs which are not yet succeeded or failed

query I have tried is :
query to fetch jobs neither succeeded nor failed

```
SELECT 
    b1.*
FROM
    JOB_LOGS b1
        LEFT JOIN
    JOB_LOGS b2 ON b1.job_id = b2.job_id
WHERE
    b2.event IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED');
```

Jobs those are not moved to inprogress in last 24 hr

```
SELECT 
    b1.*
FROM
    BG_QRTZ_EXECUTION_LOGS b1
        LEFT JOIN
    BG_QRTZ_EXECUTION_LOGS b2 ON b1.job_id = b2.job_id
WHERE
b1.event = 'ADDED' and
    b2.event NOT IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED','INPROGRESS') and b1.created_at  >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

the problem with these queries is they are returning duplicate rows

expected result for 1st query :

```
4th job id=9,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=INPROGRESS
3rd job id=7,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=ADDED
```

expected result for 2nd query :

```
3rd job id=7,crateted_at="2022-01-01 00:00:00",job_id=Job3,event=ADDED
```

Comment: "which are not yet succeeded or failed" would mean NOT IN rather than IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED')

Comment: Try provide the expected result in your question